# What's the difference between Type.Field and Value.Field?

Tags: go, struct, reflection

Following code.

```
func fieldsTest(target interface{}) ([]field, error) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(target)

    s = s.Elem()

    targetType := s.Type()

    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        f := s.Field(i)
        structField := targetType.Field(i)

    ...
}
```

If the target interface is a struct, the return value of f are the same as structField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Type.Field()` returns a value of type [`reflect.StructField`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField), and [`Value.Field()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Field) returns a value of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). So they cannot be the same.

`Type.Field()` returns a value describing the field's *type*, regardless of any actual struct value. `Value.Field()` returns a `reflect.Value` that wraps the *value* of a field of a struct value.